# Twitter's Typeahead is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I'm working on an MVC project with C# and I need a search engine. Google tells me to use [Twitter's Typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) so I'm trying to make things work but it simply does not, even whit the simplest

```
<input id="search" />

@section Script{
    <script src="~/Scripts/typeahead.jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
        var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "brown", "black"];

        $('#search').typeahead({ source: colors });
    </script>
}
```

This code leads to nothing, just an input on the page that triggers nothing. You might tell me to watch the console but it's blank. I'm losing my mind with this! I even tried to install it directly from NuGet but the result is just the same: nothing happens.

Tried so far:

- [Typeahead plugin is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261372/typeahead-plugin-is-not-working)
- [Can't get typeahead.js to work, no results will show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743078/cant-get-typeahead-js-to-work-no-results-will-show)
- http://www.arungudelli.com/jquery/simple-jquery-autocomplete-search-tutorial/
- http://mycodde.blogspot.mx/2014/12/typeaheadjs-autocomplete-suggestion.html
- http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-typeahead.php
- http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead

Comment: What messages do you get in the browser's console?

Comment: that should be @section scripts { ... } with 's'

Comment: @j08691 none, as I say in the post, the console is just blank.

Comment: @Gokhan yep, my bad, I realized that later ('s' at the end, 'S' at the beggining is right) but still nothing happens. Plus, in my Scripts bundle I have a "main" script in which I tried the same and AFTER reloading the page with Ctrl + F5, still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some research, I found [jQuery Autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) which worked since the first time, so here's the code I finally used:

```
/// <summary>
/// Obtiene el JSON de resultados de búsqueda.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="query">Búsqueda.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet, Authorize]
public ContentResult getAll(string query)
{
    DataTable dt;
    List<Models.Global.ISearchResult> _l = new List<Models.Global.ISearchResult>();
    dt = ...
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        _l.Add(new Models.Global.ResultadosContratistasModel()
        {
            value = dr["NAME"].ToString(),
            Url = "/Account/{0}".Write(dr["ACCOUNTNUM"])
        });
    }
    ...
    return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { suggestions = _l }), "application/json");
}
```

using this data model:

```
public interface ISearchResult
{
    string value { get; set; }
    string Categoría { get; }
    string Url { get; set; }
    ISearchResultData data { get; }
}
public interface ISearchResultData
{
    string category { get; set; }
    string goTo { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// objeto "data" del resultado de búsqueda rápida.
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
public struct SearchResultData : ISearchResultData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Categoría de la respuesta.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public string category { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Url a la que dirigirá el resultado.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public string goTo { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Clase serializable de Resultados de búsqueda rápida de obra.
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
public class ResultadosObraModel : ISearchResult
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Texto a mostrar como resultado de la búsqueda.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public string value { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Categoría del resultado de búsqueda.
    /// </summary>
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string Categoría
    {
        get
        {
            return "Obras";
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// URL a la que deberá dirigirse si se selecciona la opción.
    /// </summary>
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Objeto "data" con la información requerida por el plugin.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public ISearchResultData data
    {
        get{
            return new SearchResultData()
            {
                category = Categoría,
                goTo = Url
            };
        }
    }
}
```

and on the `JS` side:

```
$('input#goBox').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '/consultas/getAll',
    minChars: 2,
    lookupLimit: 10,
    groupBy: 'category',
    noSuggestionNotice: 'Presiona "Enter" para ver más resultados.',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        location.href = suggestion.data.goTo;
    }
});
```

I hope somebody will find this helpful!